# Run an .exe multiple times

Tags: batch-file

I want to run an .exe multiple times (lets say 1000 times), sequentially, using a batch file.
The problem is that everytime the program finishes, a window pops saying that the program finished and it needs us to press the "Exit" button to close everything and, through batch files, I don't know how to "press buttons".

In sum:
I want to run a program 1000 times sequentially, having to press buttons in-between them.

I hope I was clear enough and thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the [`for` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)... Batch files can't press buttons. Use something like [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com) or [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) for such tasks...

Comment: First, I would look in the options/settings/preferences of the program and its documentation if there is an option to exit the application without this annoying confirmation by the user. Second, if it is really necessary to confirm the exit of the application, I suggest to use PowerShell instead of a batch-file as it is possible with PowerShell to send a key like RETURN to an opened window to "click" on button `Exit` if it is the default button as I suppose.